Looping and incrementing page param in postman
I'm making a request for some clients in Postman, because of large number of clients it is divided in multiple pages. Page parameter is sent in url of request. How do I make loop, and increment page param in every iteration? Thank you in advance!
I've looked in documentation of postman and some other answers but couldn't make it work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes, you can request a repeat by verifying whether the current page has reached its maximum page limit.

Demo Get URL
GET https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1

Maximum Page
last_page: 34,
https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=34

Define Environment Variables
CurrentPage: 1
MaxPage: 34


Add Request
Name as Get Page
URL with CurrentPage variable.
https://catfact.ninja/facts?page={{CurrentPage}}


In Tests tab
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

let CurrentPage = responseJson.current_page;
console.log("CurrentPage:" + CurrentPage);

const MaxPage = pm.environment.get("MaxPage");

pm.test("Status code is 200", () => {
  pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.eql(200);
});

if (CurrentPage < MaxPage){
    pm.environment.set("CurrentPage", ++CurrentPage)
    console.log("has next page");
    postman.setNextRequest("Get Page"); // call request again
} else {
    console.log("no more page");
}


Run loop

Result
Total called 34 requests

Bonus
You can save response JSON data into file
How to save response file every iterationData in newman librarty

That is a good clean example.  The only aspect I would query is that local variables persist for the collection run, which you have to use as setNextRequest only works with the collection runner.  Therefore you can use a local variable to track the current page instead of having to keep overwriting and pulling back the environment variable.

Local variable also work only work at pre-request script the  environment variable can use request or tests tab for comparing or input of calling not only next page.
